# Using eventlisteners in classes

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

I'm trying to use an eventlistener in a class, but I can't make it work!

The class is ment to handle a HTTPRequest, so I'm using ResultEvent.RESULT. Can anyone help me out?

Thanks!

```
public class GetXML
{
    public var content:Object;
    public var url:String;
    public var database:HTTPService;

    public function GetXML()
    {
        this.content = content;
        this.url = url;
        this.database = database;
    }

    public function setURL(url:String):void {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public function getContent():void {
        this.database = new HTTPService();
        this.database.url = this.url;
        this.database.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT, foo);
        this.database.send();
    }

    public function foo(event:ResultEvent):void {
        Alert.show("foo");
    }

}
```

Comment: what happens if you also listen to `FaultEvent.FAULT`?

Comment: No, that function is sort of a setter. When I trace this.database.url it gives me the right url. So I don't think that is the problem? I even don't get an error... It just won't run the foo function so I think my eventlistener doesn't work?

Comment: When I listen to 'FaultEvent.FAULT' nothing happens.. As I think: the eventlistener doesn't work, but I don't know how to fix it

Comment: what is `Alert.show("foo");`? maybe the problem is there. try to make `trace(foo)`

Answer (score 0):

```
 this.database.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT, foo);
```

I think this example code was published before the API was finished.

According to the [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/rpc/http/mxml/HTTPService.html#eventSummary), the HTTPService class dispatches either two or five events (depending on the package - 'course the new documentation system Adobe is using seems to be less than perfect).

Regardless, the addEventListener() method takes, as its first argument, a string which represents the event type being listened to.  In your code, you use "ResultEvent.RESULT".  According to the [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/rpc/events/ResultEvent.html), the ResultEvent class has no such constant. (also, you are not importing the ResultEvent class, but I use Flash, not Flex, so I don't know if the ResultEvent class is core or not)

You might try, as a test, just using the actual strings:

```
 this.database.addEventListener('result', fooResult);
 this.database.addEventListener('fault', fooFault);
 this.database.addEventListener('invoke', fooInvoke);
```

Yes, I'd prefer to use constants too, but let's see if it works first. :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, according to the [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/rpc/events/ResultEvent.html#RESULT), the ResultEvent class HAS such constant.

For me:

```
    this.database.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT, foo);
```

works fine and display Alert box. I'd try:

```
    this.database.addEventListener(Event.ACTIVATE, handleActivate);
    this.database.addEventListener(Event.DEACTIVATE, handleDeactivate);
    this.database.addEventListener(FaultEvent.FAULT, handleFault);
    this.database.addEventListener(InvokeEvent.INVOKE, handleInvoke);
    this.database.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT, handleResult);
```

and check alert for each one or use Charles/HttpFox to check if we have any request or responses.

Comment: Interesting. Even via your link, I still don't see ResultEvent.RESULT listed as an available constant.

UPDATE:  I was filtering for FLASH.  no FLEX results were being displayed.  makes sense now. :)